# Is there a way to create a group of repositories in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Project in Azure DevOps with a large number of repositories. I'd like to create groups of repositories that are related so that I can grant access to them all at once rather than have to go through them one by one.

Is there a way to do that? Or is there something that I've missed that would help me grant access to a large number of repositories quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a group of repositories

For this issue, I am afraid this is currently impossible to achieve. We can set permissions for **all** repos in the Repositories of Project Settings but we cannot create groups for repos.

[image]

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) , which is our main forum for product suggestions.After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

Comment: There is a feature request on the UserVoice site that matches what I'm looking for: [Allow repos to be parented into securable folders](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1073513/allow-repos-to-be-parented-into-securable-folders.html). I have up-voted it. Hopefully others that find this question will do the same.